# Выбор схемы БД при подключении (или выборе данных) в cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

Доброго времени суток.

Есть необходимость выбрать схему БД при коннекте (или же при выборе данных) к БД Oracle. Но вот где в параметрах подключения указать ее, я не нашел. Буду рад за любую помощь в этом вопросе.

В мануале написано использовать следующие параметры:

```
cx_Oracle.connect([user, password, dsn, mode, handle, pool, threaded, twophase, events, cclass, purity, newpassword])
```

Собственно, с первыми тремя все ясно, а вот с остальными... В общем прошу вашей помощи.

**P.S.** Язык программирования *Python*, модуль *cx_Oracle*.

Спасибо.

**P.P.S.** Хорошо бы метку *"cx_Oracle"* админы добавили =)

---

Очень интересное дополнение! В объекте *Connection Object* написано следующее:

```
Connection.current_schema
    This read-write attribute sets the current schema attribute for the session.

    Note This attribute is an extension to the DB API definition.
```

Т.е. есть возможность задавать параметры чтение/запись для текущей схемы БД. А вот как ее выбрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установить схему можно, выполнив следующее:

```
c = cx_Oracle.Connection('login', 'password', 'name db')
c.current_schema = 'name schema'
```

Поподробней вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012035/changing-schema-using-cx-oracle).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, Вы неправильно перевели. "Этот доступный для чтения и записи аттрибут определяет текущую схему для сессии". Т.е. после открытия коннекта вы можете его прочитать, узнав текущую схему, и записать, установив текущую схему.